# Which is more: Energy released by nuclear fission or fusion?

Tags: nuclear-physics, estimation, radioactivity, fusion

The energy released by one fission reaction is 190MeV and the energy released by one fusion reaction is 24.7MeV. Then by my common sense 190>24.7 so energy released by fission>fusion but the energy released by fusion reaction is 3 to 4 times greater than fission. Please explain me how. I hope 190>24.7

Comment: What sources are you citing for all your numbers and for the statement "energy released by fusion reaction is 3 to 4 times greater than fission"?

Comment: Please say what you are fusing and what fissile material you are comparing it to. There are many elements in the actinide series which have many modes of fission, all at different energies. Fusion of any elements are also at different energies.

Answer (score 2):

> Then by my common sense 190>24.7 so energy released by fission>fusion

The question is which **fuel** produces more energy, not which **reaction**.

You have failed to consider the mass of the fuel put into the reactions. Uranium is much heaver than hydrogen.

A single atom of U235 produces ~170 MeV (kinetic).

170/235 = 0.72

Two hydrogen isotopes, D2 and T3, produce 17.6 MeV.

17.6/5 = 3.5

Thus fusion is much more powerful than fission when you consider the amount of energy produced from a given mass of fuel:

3.5/0.72 = 4.8

I suspect your 24.7 MeV and resulting "3 to 4 times" is simply using a different reaction and/or accounting for energy that cannot actually be extracted.

Answer (score -1):

For a give reaction energies of fission and fusion are roughly equal and opposite. If fissioning element A into elements B, C released energy, that means that A had more internal energy than B and C put together. If fusioning B and C into A released energy, it means that A had less internal energy than B and C put together. Both can't be true at once. If fusion releases net energy, fission must cost net energy, and vice-versa.

Comment: Given the disparities in energy release by the OP, it is not clear that they are referring to one reaction running backwards or forwards...